# How can I use different data templates for pivot items

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, pivot

I am using a Pivot control with databinding.

The ItemsSource for the pivot is bound to a collection.

The ItemTemplate is includes a listbox and that is bound to a another collection via databinding.   All is working okay and everything is being populated as it should be.

What I now need to do is alter things slightly that the data displayed  for the first Pivot item is different to all the others... i.e. I would like a different datatemplate for the first Pivot Item.

- thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common pattern I've seen used here is to create a `DataTemplateSelector`, which extends `ContentControl` and determines the template at runtime.

[Windows Phone Geek have an article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector) that takes you through what is required. Don't forget to bind `Content="{Binding}"`, that's something that always trips me up ;)